# PHP: How to get time difference in array

Tags: php, arrays, date, datetime

I have **time_in** and **time_out** for my app.

I have an **array** which have a key of `0,2,4..` so this is the **time_in** while `1,3,5..` is the **time_out**.

I want to get the **total working hours**.

Here is the example array below:

```
$time = [
    [0] => 08:12:00,
    [1] => 12:01:00 
    [2] => 08:14:00, 
    [3] => 12:05:00,
    [4] => 13:13:00,
    [5] => 17:13:00,
    [6] => 13:03:00,
    [7] => 17:00:00,
    ];
```

**Result:** `17 hours and 1 minute`

Is it possible that you can get the time difference using array? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See my answer, date() is not a method to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could be tempted to use date() to output the times, but date() is meant for dates and not to output times.
If date is used then anything above 24 hours will be incorrect.
Instead use math to calculate the times.

```
foreach(array_chunk($time, 2) as $t){
    $seconds[] = strtotime($t[1])-strtotime($t[0]);
}

echo "hours: " . floor(array_sum($seconds)/3600) . "\n";
echo "minutes: " . (array_sum($seconds)%3600)/60 . "\n";
```

See example, I also added a date() just to prove that it's not the method to use:
https://3v4l.org/m2E27

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` with `strtotime`

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($time as $k => $v){
  if($k % 2 == 1){
    $sum += strtotime($time[$k])-strtotime($time[$k-1]);
  }
}
echo date("H:i:s", $sum);
```

As per suggestion by Andreas updated answer:-

```
$seconds = 0;
foreach($time as $k => $v){
if($k % 2 == 1){
  $seconds += strtotime($time[$k])-strtotime($time[$k-1]);
 }
}
echo floor($seconds / 3600) . gmdate(":i:s", $seconds % 3600);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/gOAId)

Comment: This gives incorrect times when you go past 24 hours. Since it's working hours that is being calculated then we can assume it's more than 24 hours

Comment: @Andreas you means the difference between 2 times goes more then 24 hr, this solution will be wrong ?

Comment: Yes and if the sum also is above 24 hours. See link in my answer